# In the very beginning of "The Matrix" a trace program is shown, is it a real trace program from the nineties or just a fancy video animation?

Tags: the-matrix

In the very beginning of "The Matrix" a trace program is shown, is it a real trace program from the nineties or just a fancy video animation?
The program is used to trace a phone line, apparently or the location of a phone call. Law enforcement managed to trace Trinity activity and her task.

Comment: It's just a fancy animation; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHacking

Comment: The link does not mention "The Matrix", obviously your answer is pretty common sense, but the real question remains.

Comment: Ask yourself: What is easier, doing a fancy video animation, or setting up a complete 80s switchboard system to be able to run a trace program on it?

Comment: 80s? You meant 90s, right?

Comment: I have read hundreds of facts about The Matrix triology, this was never explicitly mentioned that it was an actual program. I am pretty sure that if it would have been a real one, they must had made that information public and it would have been a top fun fact about the triology.